# "No space left on device", Spark Job Terminated : No proper solution yet in stackoverflow

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**I have following file structure if i do df -h  in any of the slaves or master device**

```
  Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/xvda1            7.9G  4.4G  3.5G  57% /
    tmpfs                 7.4G  4.0K  7.4G   1% /dev/shm
    /dev/xvdb              37G  3.3G   32G  10% /mnt
    /dev/xvdf              37G  2.0G   34G   6% /mnt2
    /dev/xvdv             500G   33M  500G   1% /vol0
```

**My spark-env.sh looks like this**

```
export SPARK_WORKER_DIR="/vol0"
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.local.dir=/vol0"
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS="/vol0/"
```

But Still i am getting "No space left on device" error and job gets terminated during saving files.

I Have one dataset having 200 files each of 1GB each and another dataset having 200 files each of 45MB.  I am joining them and saving to new file in s3.

```
DataFrame dataframe1= sqlContext.read().format("json").json(outputGrowth).coalesce(50);
        dataframe1.registerTempTable("dataframe1");



        DataFrame dataframe2 = sqlContext.read().format("json").json(pdiPath);
        dataframe2.registerTempTable("dataframe2");

        //Joining two tables
        String query = "join dataframe1 and dataframe2";
        DataFrame resultPDI = sqlContext.sql(query);
        dataPDI.unpersist();
        growthData.unpersist();
        resultPDI.write().mode("overwrite").json(outputPDI);
```

So, How can i set my spark to store data in /vol0 instead of other file  /mnt/spark.

I have tried different solutions from stackoverflow, and some blogs no any solutions are working for me.

Can anyone help me to get rid of this problem. i am using 10 device m1.large  in Aws server.

Comment: There are other configurations which might cause such issues. For example log placements, HDFS local dirs etc. All are by default pointing to /tmp. I would start investigating them.

Comment: Thank you @AssafMendelson for your suggestion. what might be those parameters ? can You help me . and can you suggest my what type of instances should i use ?

Comment: @AssafMendelson   . where is the file that log palcement setting can be configured ?

Comment: There are many logs. For spark, for hdfs, for yarn etc. Each of these can cause the issue. For spark itself this is configured using spark.eventLog.dir. or using environment variable SPARK_LOG_DIR. In any case I would go over the configuration documentation for spark, hdfs and yarn and figure out all the directories which can be configured.

Answer (score 1):

You can create cimply create the  symlink for /mnt/spark to /val0 if you are using ubuntu as below

```
ln -s /val0 /mnt/spark
```

so with the help of symblink you can refer /val0 with /mnt/spark. For more info go to below link http://ubuntuhak.blogspot.in/2013/04/symbolic-links-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: but how to do this same in all slaves , manually ? or we can set this in any of the configuration file ?

Comment: yess you need to manually create symblink on all the worker nodes but u can also try with this configuration spark.local.dir spark uses this for its scratch work and by default its /tmp may be ur /tmp folder had not enough space

Comment: I think this is not possible to do this manually as data will grow , slaves will be more than hundreds in number.